Question coming from Cosmological Perturbation
We consider the following scalar perturbation on the FRW metric:
$$ ds^2 = -(1 + 2\phi)dt^2 +2a\partial_i B dx^i dt + a^2 \left( (1 - 2\psi)\delta_{ij} + 2\partial_{ij}E\right) dx^i dx^j $$
where $\phi$, $B$, $\psi$ and $E$ are perturbations and $a$ is the scale factor.
I want to know why this is the only way to do perturbation? I got to know that it has something to do with 'irreducible representation of the rotation group' but I don't understand it. Is there any reference where this is explained?

Hi Shivam. I have converted your equation to MathJax but you might want to check it is correct.

Welcome to the physics StackExchange (seeing that you are a new user)! For a reference to why we do perturbation theory this way, with the goal in mind to compute (typically) the curvature and scalar power spectra (2-point correlation functions), can be found in Baumann's TASI lectures on inflation (TASI Lectures on Inflation chapter 10 and appendix A with references therein) and chapter 6 of his textbook.
The quick answer is that the perturbations of the metric are not uniquely defined and depend upon our choice of coordinates i.e. our choice of gauge.
When that particular perturbed metric is written down a specific time slicing of the spacetime was introduced and specific spatial coordinates were defined on these time slices. If a different choice of coordinates were chosen, then the values of the perturbation variables change.
As an example, consider the typical FRWL metric in conformal time. We then perform a change of variables being a diffeomorphism transformation of the form $\text{diff}:x^i\mapsto \tilde{x}^i = x^i + \xi^i(\eta,\mathbf{x})$ where $\eta$ is the conformal time related to $t$ as $d\eta = dt/a(t)\implies a(\eta) = -1/(H\eta)$. Then, $dx^i = d\tilde{x}^i - \partial_\eta \xi^i d\eta - \partial_k \xi^i d\tilde{x}^k$ leads to the FRWL metric becoming
\begin{align}
ds^2 & = a^2(\eta)\left(-d\eta^2 + \delta_{ij}dx^i dx^j\right)\nonumber\\
& = a^2(\eta)\left(-d\eta^2 - 2\partial_\eta\xi^i d\tilde{x}^i d\eta + (\delta_{ij}  - 2\partial_{(i}\xi_{j)})\right)
\end{align}
where we can identify the metric perturbations read off from your metric as $B_i = -\partial_\eta\xi_i$ and $E_i = -\xi_i$. But we can always remove this ficticious gauge modes by transforming back to the original coordinates. I also cut off the metric at order $\mathcal{O}(\xi^2)$.
It is only after understanding the gauge invariance of the perturbations, that the worry of decomposing the perturbations into their respective scalar, vector, and tensor mode (SVT-decomposition) takes place (of which you only ever really care about scalar and tensor perturbations with respect to inflation).
